# How to divide responsibility between LDAP and RDBMS

Tags: ldap, rdbms

I'm a lead developer on a project which is building web applications for my companies SaaS offering.  We are currently using LDAP to store user data such as IDs, passwords, contanct details, preferences and other user specific data.

One of the applications we are building is a reporting service that will both collect and present management information to our end users.  Obviously this service will require a RDBMS but it will also need to access user data stored in LDAP.

As I see it we have a two basic implementation options:

1. Duplicate user data in both LDAP and the RDBMS.
2. Have the reporting service access LDAP whenever it needs user data.

Although duplicating data (and implementing the mechanisms to make this happen) as suggested in option 1 seems the wrong way to go, my gut feeling is that option 2 would not perform well enough (how do you 'join' LDAP data to RDBMS data as efficiently as a pure RDBMS implementation?).

I did find a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491184/choosing-between-a-directory-server-a-k-a-ldap-database-and-an-rdbms) but I'm still unsure which approach to take. I'd be interested in seeing what people thought of either option or perhaps other options.

Comment: An example of where this is an issue is where we might implement a report of user logins. We would want a list of login events and some associated user data such as display name and telephone number.  The login events would be stored in the RDBMS but the user data would be in LDAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you feel that duplicating data would be the wrong way to go? Reporting tools (web based and otherwise) are mostly built around RDBMS's, so any mix'n'match will introduce unnecessary complexities. Reports are likely to need to be changed fairly frequently (from experience), so you want them to be as simple as possible. The data you store about users is unlikely to change its format very often, so once you have your import function working, you won't need to touch it again.

The only obstacle I can see is latency: how do you ensure that your RDBMS copy is up to date? You might need to ensure that your updating code writes to both destinations. Personally, also, I wouldn't necessarily use LDAP for application specific personal preferences: LDAP can't handle transactions, so what happens when data is updated from several directions? (Transactionality is of course also a problem with letting updaters write to both stores...) I'd rather let the RDBMS be the master for most data, and let LDAP worry only about identity, credentials and entitlements, which are rarely changed and only for one set of purposes. For myself, LDAP's ability to deal with hierarchical data isn't all that great a selling point.

Data duplication is not always a bad thing, especially when the usage scenarios are different enough.